# I can't close jQuery UI dialog modal on overlay click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I run it on:

```
@Html.ActionLink("TEST", "About", "Home", null,
       new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "test"})
```

I show it like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                    modal: true, 
                    width: 600,
                    height: 450

                })
                .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });

        $(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () { $("#data-dialog-id").dialog("close"); });
    });
```

Last block of script should close dialog on overlay click (as I think) but it doesn't work?

This is whole page when I open modal window:

```
   <html class=" js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/document_iterator.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/find_proxy.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/get_html_text.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/global_constants.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/name_injection_builder.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/number_injection_builder.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/string_finder.js"></script><script src="chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl/change_sink.js"></script><meta name="document_iterator.js"><meta name="find_proxy.js"><meta name="get_html_text.js"><meta name="global_constants.js"><meta name="name_injection_builder.js"><meta name="number_injection_builder.js"><meta name="string_finder.js"><meta name="change_sink.js"></head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>            

<div class="searchCityBox">
    <div id="logoBox" style="height: 25px; float: left;">
        <a href="">
            <img alt="logo" src="/Content/images/Logo.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2px; float: right;">

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
    function onItemSelect(item) {

        //var siteRootUrl = 'localhost:51168';

        window.location.href = item;
    }

    $(function () {
        $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Navigation/Search', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchTerm: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Country.CountryCode + ':' + item.Name,
                                value: '/' + 'CityPage?country=' + item.Country.CountryCode + '&city=' + item.Name
                                //value: '/' + item.Country.CountryCode + '/' + item.Name
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                onItemSelect(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    #autocomplete
    {
        width: 250px;
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
</style>
<div>
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="City Search..." class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</div>        

    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2px; float: right;">
            [ <a href="/login">Log On</a> ]

    </div>
</div>
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <style>
    .ui-dialog-titlebar
    {
        display: none;
    }

</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                    modal: true,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 450

                })
                .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });

        $(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () {
            alert($("#data-dialog-id").size()); 
            $(".dialog").dialog("close")
        });
    });
</script>
<p>
    Welcome to , !
</p>
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="test" href="/Home/About">TEST</a>

        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>


<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; "></ul><div style="outline-width: 0px; outline-style: initial; outline-color: initial; height: auto; width: 600px; position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 379px; display: block; z-index: 1002; " class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-test"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-test">&nbsp;</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div class="dialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="test" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 434px; ">


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About Us</title>
    <link href="/Content/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">







    <div class="page">
        <header>            

<div class="searchCityBox">
    <div id="logoBox" style="height: 25px; float: left;">
        <a href="">
            <img alt="logo" src="/Content/images/MyCityNookLogo.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2px; float: right;">

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>
    #autocomplete
    {
        width: 250px;
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
</style>
<div>
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="City Search..." class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</div>        

    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2px; float: right;">
            [ <a href="/login">Log On</a> ]

    </div>
</div>
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.
</p>

        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>


</div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; "></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1002; "></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1003; "></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1004; "></div></div><div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="z-index: 1001; width: 1349px; height: 568px; "></div><ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; "></ul><ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1003; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; "></ul></body><span id="skype_highlighting_settings" display="none" autoextractnumbers="1"></span><object id="skype_plugin_object" location.href="http://localhost:51168/" location.hostname="localhost" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: -100px; top: -100px; " width="0" height="0" type="application/x-vnd.skype.click2call.chrome.5.6.0"></object></html>
```

Comment: I must mess something with this ID's ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selecting an id "data-dialog-id" but I don't see where you set it on the link.

Change the following code in the last line from

```
$("#data-dialog-id").dialog("close");
```

to this

```
$(".openDialog").dialog("close");
```

and it should probably work

Update:

Ok, I created a working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kufi/R4spe/)

The problem is your last line, you need to use $("#test") not $("#data-dialog-id")

Comment: Does the click function on the overlay ever get called? Could you verify that?

Comment: Yes when I click on overlay it gets on that line, but just pass over it and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked my fiddle in my updated post? There it works correctly.

Comment: I have used exactly same code as in fiddle and I got alert('t') but close didn't work :(

Comment: Hm, ok. Could you provide the html code you get when the dialog is opened, the seems to be something odd there ;)

Comment: I added whole page source in my question.

Comment: Hm, ok. Are you sure there isn't a second div with the "test" id somewhere on the page? What do you get if you put alert($("#test").size()) into the function before $("#test").dialog("close"); Alternatively, try to exchange $("#test").dialog("close"); with $(".dialog").dialog("close")

Comment: I get just number 1 in alert. It's only id test

Comment: Could you post the html of the whole page? Not just of the dialog? Because at the moment my local version is working, regardless of what I'm doing with it ^^

Comment: Strange, for me it's working perfectly. Does this line in the ui-widget-overlay return true: alert($("#test").dialog('isOpen'));?

Comment: Ok, so it isn't recognized as a correct dialog. Maye something with the content isn't right. Try to load it without the content and look if it then works.

Comment: If I remove ".load(this.href);" from script code then it works but not loading my controller/view. Is there any other way to pass controller/view in dialog?

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with the html your trying to load. As soon as you load it, jquery somehow breaks the dialog. Are you loading the whole html into the dialog (with the head section)? Try to use the load method like this: load(this.href + " body") so it only inserts the body content of the html.

Comment: It was asp mvc issue in the end :) I need to return PartialView() from controller action.